# .rc startup file for Ubuntu 14.04 (~.xinitrc fails)

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, ubuntu-14.04

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm trying to make some commands run automatically after login in Ubuntu.

Before I used Ubuntu 12.04 and here I had a `~/.xinitrc` file that was sourced fine after each log in.

However, this seems to be broken when I moved to 14.04.

I tried renaming my file to `~/.xsessionrc`, `~/.xsession` and `~/.Xresource`. However, the problem remains.

Btw, sourcing manually (`source .xinitrc`) runs the contents of that file successfully btw.

Answer (score 1):

Make an example "Hello World" script using zenity ( `sudo apt install zenity` ) to run at startup.

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --notification --text="Hello world!"
```

Save the script as Hello-world.sh anywhere in your `/home/your-user-name/` directory, right-click it -> select *Properties* -> *Permissions* tab and put a check mark in the checkbox to the right of where it says: *Allow executing file as program*.

How to add a script to your Startup Applications

1. In the Dash search for *Startup Applications* and open it.
2. Click the **Add** button to add an additional startup program.
3. Click the **Browse** button and browse to the location of your Hello-world.sh script and click the **Open** button to enter the location of the script in the Command: field.
4. Add the string `bash` before the location in the Command: field so that the command has the form: `bash /path/to/script`
5. Give your new startup application any descriptive Name and after Comment: add a descriptive comment.
6. Click the **Save** button to save. Click the **Close** button to close the Startup Applications Preferences window.

Now every time after you boot the computer and login to your Ubuntu desktop environment, you will see a little notification window on your desktop that says *Hello world!* . In the same way you can add any bash script to your startup applications.

You can also run a single command at startup instead of a bash script. In Step 3 enter a bash command in the Command: field instead of browsing to the location of a bash script. Skip Step 4 (You don't need to add the string `bash` before a bash command.).